# I need to sort a dictionary by order of value and RETURN it

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have this code:

```
new_dict = {"1":[], "2":[], "3":[], "4":[]}
for coordinates in numbers:
    if coordinates == (48, 12):
        new_dict["1"].append(coordinates)
    elif coordinates in [(68, 125), (54, 160), (20, 137)]:
        new_dict["2"].append(coordinates)
    elif coordinates in [(113, 69), (152, 53)]:
        new_dict["3"].append(coordinates)
    elif coordinates == (108, 149):
        new_dict["4"].append(coordinates)
sorted_dict = sorted(new_dict.items())
for x,y in sorted_dict:
    print (x,y)
```

prints:

```
1 [(48, 12)]
2 [(68, 125), (54, 160), (20, 137)]
3 [(113, 69), (152, 53)]
4 [(108, 149)]
```

Instead of just printing it in the function. How can I return it and not change it into a tuple and keep it the way it is.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `collections.OrderedDict` for this task.

Comment: Check your indention. It is enough to sort once.

Comment: Sorting it changes it into a tuple for a reason, you know. Dicts are **unordered collections**. You can't just magically change the way they work because it doesn't suit your needs. You'll have to use a different data structure.

Comment: How do you want the output to be?

Comment: @AniMenon it should be the same as I showed above. But instead it should be returned and not printed while still keeping it a dict.

Comment: The output should not change as shown above. I just need to return this instead of printing so that I can use it elsewhere.

Comment: As mentioned, you cannot sort the real dictionary. Use ordereddict() or write your own object with dictionary-like interface. But I gathered you want values sorted, or it was language misunderstanding? If you want to sort values, use .values(), not .items() anyway. Dictionary cannot be sorted because it sorts itself according to internal hashes which it uses for fast data access.

Comment: ```return collections.OrderedDict(sorted(new_dict.items())```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return '\n'.join([' '.join([str(x),str(y)]) for x,y in sorted_dict])
```

From what you write I collect that you'd want it to be returned 'the same as I showed above'.

Edit: sorry didn't put elements `x,y` it in `str()`, corrected now